# Map C++ structure to Java Structure

Tags: java, c++, jna

I am trying to call C++ function present within a dll file,C++ function takes structure object as parameter and function will assign values to it.
I am making use this through Java native calls and my program is below,

```
public class WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS extends Structure {
    public static class ByReference extends WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS implements Structure.ByReference {

    }
public int AddressFamily;

public byte[] Address = new byte[20];

public WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS() {
}

public WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS(Pointer p) {
    super(p);
}

public byte[] getByteArray() {
    return Address;
}

@Override
protected List getFieldOrder() {
    return Arrays.asList("AddressFamily", "Address");
}
}
```

I am getting values for the AddressFamily correctly but not for the Address. looks like something going wrong in the data structure between the byte array in c++ and the java structure byte array defined. Any help ?

The C++ structure for it is,

```
typedef struct _WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS {
  DWORD AddressFamily;
  BYTE  Address[20];
} WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS, *PWTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS;
```

Comment: please provide us some sample, the data you expect and the data you get -which is wrong-

Comment: take a look at [this](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/20899351/How-to-pass-Byte-array-from-C-to-Java.html), it seems you need to change your C++ side a little bit

Comment: @Joe 
Actual : [-88, -20, 10, -74, 106, -20, -35, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 64, -19, -35, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
Expected : [10.182.106.236]

Answer (score 1):

In C++, static-length arrays declared in a struct are inlined into the struct. So your C++ code is, structure-wise, roughly equivalent to:

```
typedef struct _WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS {
  DWORD AddressFamily;
  BYTE Address1;
  BYTE Address2;
  // ...
  BYTE Address20;
} WTS_CLIENT_ADDRESS;
```

Which is, to my knowledge, the only way you will be able to map `Address` in Java, since there is no better mapping from Java arrays to C++ array fields. Note that this differs from C++ array parameters in functions, which are basically pointers and therefore work properly.

Answer (score 0):

What if you pass a single byte to java? There are two possible problems: **Array** and **Type** or maybe both of them. if a single byte can be passed to Java with no problem, then try to use **BYTE *Address** instead of **BYTE Address[]**. If it does not help, try to pass an array of chars instead of byte **char Address[]** or **char *Address**. Let me know if it's resolved.